# Find position of symmetrical array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Referring to picture below at [here](https://ibb.co/qssJk3K), x and y means coordinates. For symmetrical coordinates part, the numbering will be symmetrical also and **if its not symmetrical,** it will keep adding i+1 index. For coordinates that is equal to each other side by side, the index will stay constant. I have attached a codepen file at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/RwxeWzb?editors=0011) for javascript playground. The output that I want is the index in array as shown in picture. How do I go about in solving this algorithm :)?

Thank you for reading

```
   x_all=[102,152, 202,252 ,202,152, 302,454 ,8745,8745 ,25, 25, 23, 10 , 332, 10 , 67 , 90, 67 ,8967];
   y_all=[12, 153, 20,  52, 20, 153, 302,8745,9065,9065, 52, 34, 9  ,232, 9  , 232, 89  ,91,  89 ,8954];

arr=[];
jj=0
for (let i=0;i<x_all.length;i++){
  if (x_all[i+1]==x_all[i-1]){
    console.log(i)
     jj=jj-1;
    arr.push(jj+1)
  }
    arr.push(jj)
  jj=jj+1;

}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Hi Jessica, welcome to SO. Be sure to check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, what specifically is wrong with your solution (what is your current output and what should it be, etc.), and what else have you tried? It'd also be helpful if you put your code in the SO snippet so it can be ran here without having to go to Codepen.io.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER DISCLAIMER**: I did not fully comprehend the question (The image in the question - https://ibb.co/qssJk3K - is also not accessible!) - and so this is in no way the complete answer.

but meh ‍♀️ found it somewhat interesting to solve so tried [this](https://codepen.io/KZJ/pen/wvpYdgX?editors=0012). Hope it helps.

Here's what I tried - For

> `x_all=[102,152, 202,252 ,202,152, 302,454 ,8745,8745 ,25, 25, 23, 10 , 332, 10 , 67 , 90, 67 ,8967];`

1. Found enclosing palindromes and added them to a *palindrome_x*

   ```
    [[152,202,252,202,152],
       [8745,8745],
       [25,25],
       [10,332,10],
       [67,90,67]]
   ```
2. Used an *indexes* array to push and pop as required.
   So the

> `Final Output For x: 1,2,3,4,3,2,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,10,11,10,12,13,12,14`

Not sure if this is what is required... But there are commented *console.log*-er statements for further debugging.